# What's the more common way to refer to a road with 180° curves?

Tags: word-usage, expressions, american-english

***A hairpin road*** is a road with hairpin turns or bends.

[image: Road zigzagging up a hill]

According to Wikipedia:

> - ***[A hairpin bend](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpin_turn)*** , named  for its resemblance to a hairpin/bobby pin, is a bend in a road with a very acute inner angle, making it necessary for an oncoming vehicle to turn almost 180° to continue on the road.
> - Such turns in ramps and trails ***may be called switchbacks in American English***.

I've always thought, as it appears from the article above, that the common expression to refer to such a curvy road is "hairpin road" and that "switchback road"  is a less common AmE variant.

But checking with  [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hairpin%20road%2Cswitchback%20road&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chairpin%20road%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cswitchback%20road%3B%2Cc0) "switchback road" turns out to be the more common expression both in BrE and AmE.

Question:

What is the  the above described road more commonly called in BrE and AmE?

Are there alternative expressions to refer to it?

Comment: I would not understand "switchback road" to mean that, but rather to mean a road with many ups and downs and peaks and troughs: it might also be very windy in plan, but need not be.

Comment: I've always (in the US) seen/heard it referred to as "switchback".  IIRC,there is a use of that term in the movie Exodus.  "Hairpin" is idiomatic for the individual turns, but not for the road in general.

Comment: See the extensive discussion (11 answers) at ELL's [What is this type of road called in English?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46490/what-is-this-type-of-road-called-in-english)....

Comment: A hairpin turn can be the singular and a switchback road is comprised of multiple hairpins.

Comment: If it were a hiking trail, it would be called "the switchbacks".  Example:  "One mile after the stream with the log across it, you come to the switchbacks.  You will gain about 200 feet of altitude on the switchbacks, and then the trail rises gently for another 2 miles."   Universally understood among US hikers.  I'm not authoritative about a road that one drives on.

Comment: I have seldom, if ever, heard the term *switchback* used for a road in Britain, though I have heard Americans say it, not knowing exactly what they meant. We would call such bends *hairpins* or a *succession of hairpins*.

Comment: Where does this come from: "*A hairpin road is a road with hairpin turns or bends.*" Is it a quote from somewhere? To my mind, *hairpin road* is never said. A curve/bend/turn might be a hairpin curve, and a road might have many hairpin turns, but it would not be called a *hairpin road*. You could say that it is a road that has some (or many) hairpin turns.

Comment: The illustration shows a road which zig-zags up a steep slope, moderating the gradient of the road by cutting back and forth across the face of the slope. The question does not specifically refer to the gradient or the fact that the road climbs/descends. Is the gradient important to the question?

Comment: @Spagirl - not really, I posted that picture because these roads are generally found on mountains .

Comment: @Josh61 I've just seen in Dan's answer that the gradient is definitional for 'switchback', but I would say it isn't for 'hairpin'. So you could have hairpin bends which were not switchbacks, though it is difficult to imagine any situations where you had a series of them which was not steep. Single hairpins can occur for other reasons, location of a bridge, for example. The UK has vanishingly few such roads, all the steep passes I can think of, Bealach na Ba, Ratagan Pass, Wrynose and Hardknott Passes are much less regular, more winding than strictly alternating directon.

Answer (score 2):

A [serpentine](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/serpentine?s=t) road seems to fit the bill.

Here's something actually called Serpentine Road:

[image]

Comment: Serpentine wound be  a valid BrE and AmE expression, but what about hairpin road and switchback road?

Comment: You'd be understood and agreed with; however, to my ear, both terms would sooner apply to individual bends rather than an entire road. But I'm weird like that. Don't take my word for anything unless I insist you do.

Comment: Great word, lovely picture, but not a familiar usage to me (very poetic).

Comment: @Dan: Well, how often do you hear "hairpin" or "switchback" in Bristol? "Meandering" is the best one could hope for in South England. All the seriously steep slopes are on the other side of Hadrian's rampart, where the heather bloometh.

Comment: @Ricky - a qualified 'yes' to that.  There are a surprising number of roads that turn quite modest hills into nail-biting drives even in the soft south.  Probably roads that were previously mule tracks.

Comment: Serpentine addresses the changes in direction in the horizontal plane, but not the change in elevation. 'Serpentine doesn't tell you that it is steep. Mind you, now that I look the OP doesn't specify steep and a bend can be hairpin without climbing....

Answer (score 1):

A *switchback* is a section of trail or road that switches back: turns back on itself, but typically while also ascending or descending.

There are typically many switchbacks in a switchback trail (or road).
Some of them might be hairpin turns - those curves that are really quite tight corners. A curve can be qualified as *hairpin* if it is a tight curve, but you would never refer to the trail or road itself as a *hairpin*.  The turn of a switchback is often a *hairpin* turn, but it need not be.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK you hear people advising you that there are '*tight*' corners and '*hairpin bends*' ahead.  Neither 'hairpin road' nor 'switchback road' sounds right to me (although both usages are completely clear).  I'd say 'a road with a lot of hairpin(bend)s'. (probably the lack of 'a word' is because there aren't many such roads anywhere near most UK residents).

*Switchback* sounds American and has more than a whiff of the fairground about it (rollercoasters and such).  The OED says '*switchback*' is *applied to a form of railway used on steep slopes, consisting of a zigzag series of lines connected by switches, at each of which the train or car is ‘switched back’ or reversed in direction (and that it is applied in N. America to a tight bend on an ascending road or trail)*

Comment: So, in the UK what wound be the common expression to refer to a road with a series  a of hairpin bends?

Answer (score 0):

A **[twisting road](https://www.google.fr/search?q=twisting%20road&biw=1366&bih=620&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu2LnWg9XKAhUCUxoKHVO6C6wQsAQIGw)** has many sharp turns (not necessarily hairpins), but is more tortuous than a "winding road".

Answer (score -1):

You might want to consider, ***zigzag road***.

> zigzag (ˈzigzag) adjective (of a line, road etc.) having sharp bends or angles from side to side. a zigzag path through the woods. [Kernerman English Multilingual Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Zigzag)
>
> [**Ngram**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=zigzag+road%2Cswitchback+road%2Chairpin+road&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Czigzag%20road%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cswitchback%20road%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chairpin%20road%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: This Ngram says little to nothing about current usage and leaves out other uses such as serpentine road.

Comment: But *zigzag* does not imply that it's climbing (or descending) a mountain, the way *switchback* does in AmE. Of course, I don't know whether the OP wants this implication; I'm just extrapolating from the picture he chose.